# Find max value for an Element at a Position in an Array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of sensor data where each document has the following structure:

```
[{ _id: 592d9b0e276bd2136caacca0,
    name: 5
    light: [ ... ],
    temperature: [ ... ],
    UV: [ ... ],
    RA: [ ... ]
}]
```

Each array of each sensor has a length of 100 elements.

How can I, for example, retrieve which name has the document with the highest value for the temperature at position 42 (in the array of temperature )?

There are a lot of solutions for the first element or last element but I can't seem to find how to solve it for arbitrary positions of the array.

This is what I already have:

```
db.sensors.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$name" },
    { $sort: { "temperature": -1} },
    { $limit: 1}
]);
```

But as you see, the line with "{ $sort: { "temperature": -1 } }" will not work. I really do not understand how to specify that I want the sorting only for the element at position 42 of the temperature array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for the value at a given position then you can use [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) to return the value at the supplied position. For which the common array notation is `n-1`, so the 42nd position is `41` from the index starting at `0`:

```
db.sensors.aggregate({
  { "$addFields": {
     "pos": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$temperature", 41 ] } }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "pos": -1 } },
  { "$limit": 1 }
])
```

You can even speed up the process by using [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) as a query argument to only bother looking at arrays that actually have 42 elements, as anything else would be discarded from consideration:

```
db.sensors.aggregate({
  { "$match": { "temperature.41": { "$exists": true } } },
  { "$addFields": {
     "pos": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$temperature", 41 ] } }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "pos": -1 } },
  { "$limit": 1 }
])
```

Also noting that in earlier versions without the [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) pipeline operator, you instead specify all the fields you want to return with [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/):